# Integrals involving powers and beta (or hypergeometric) function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, closed-form

> I have the three following integrals, very similar the one to the others,
>   $$I_1^{(p)}(N)\equiv\frac{1}{2^{N+p}}\int_0^1(1+t)^{N-1}(1-t)^pB\left(\frac{1}{t+1};N+p+1,N\right)\text{d}t$$
>   $$I_2^{(p)}(N)\equiv 2^{2N-1}\int_0^1 t^{N-1}(1-t)^p\left(1-\frac{N+p+1}{N-1}t\right)B\left(\frac{1}{t+1};N+p+1,N\right)\text{d}t$$
>   $$I_3^{(p)}(N)\equiv\frac{2^{2N-1}}{N-1}\int_0^1 t^{N-1}(1-t)^pB\left(\frac{1}{t+1};N+p+1,N\right)\text{d}t$$
>   where $N\in\mathbb{N}$, $p>0$ and $B(x;a,b)$ is the incomplete beta function
>   $$B(x;a,b)=\int_0^x u^{a-1}(1-u)^{b-1}\text{d}u.$$
>   What I am trying to find is a closed form for the quantity
>   $$I^{(p)}(N)\equiv I_1^{(p)}(N)-I_2^{(p)}(N)+I_3^{(p)}(N).$$

I obtained the above expressions by starting from double integrals of the form given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3257400/double-integrals-involving-incomplete-beta-function) and proceeding in the way described in the answer. Once I arrived to these single integrals, I was not able to proceed any further, nor to do relevant simplifications by putting all together in $I^{(p)}(N)$, which results in
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
I^{(p)}(N)&=\int_0^1t^{N-1}(1-t)^pB\left(\frac{1}{t+1};N+p+1,N\right)\\[8pt]
&\quad\cdot\left\{\frac{1}{2^{N+p}}\left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)^{N-1}+\frac{2^{2N-1}}{N-1}\left[(N+p+1)t-(N-2)\right]\right\}\text{d}t.
\end{split}\end{equation}

I cannot think of a proper useful substitution, and I obtained nothing by trying some, e.g. to transform the first argument of the beta function as $1/(t+1)\to t$.

**Edit1:** I managed to reduce the starting expression to
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
&I^{(p)}(N)\equiv R(N,p)+J(N,p)\\[7pt]
&=R(N,p)+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1t^{N+p}(1-t)^{N-1}\left[B\left(\frac{1}{2t};N,p+1\right)+\frac{2^{2N}}{N-1}B\left(\frac{1-t}{t};N,p+1\right)\right]\text{d}t
\end{split}\end{equation}
where $R(N,p)$ is given by (I will provide the steps as soon as I can)
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
R(N,p)&=B\left(\frac{1}{2};N+p+1,N\right)\left\{\frac{1}{2^{N+p}(p+1)}{}_2F_1(1,1-N;p+2;-1)+\right.\\[7pt]
&\left.\quad+\frac{2^{2N-1}}{N-1}\left[(N+p+1)B(N+1,p+1)-(N-2)B(N,p+1)\right]\right.\\[7pt]
&\left.\quad+B\left(\frac{1}{2};N,p+1\right)\right\}-B\left(\frac{1}{2};N,p+1\right)B(N,N+p+1)\\[7pt]
&\quad-\frac{1}{N-1}B(p+2,2N){}_2F_1(1,p+2;2N+p+2;-1).\end{split}
\end{equation}
Now the remaining integral appears to me simpler than the starting one, and I noted that by using the relation
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1}
B(z;a,b)=B(a,b)-B(1-z;b,a),
\end{equation}
in the square brakets one obtains something of the form
$$B\left(\frac{u}{2};p+1,N\right)+\frac{2^{2N}}{N-1}B\left(u;p+1,N\right),$$
i.e. the two beta functions differ only by a factor $2$ in their first argument.

Integrating by parts the integral in $J(N,p)$ I get
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
J(N,p)&=B\left(\frac{1}{2};N,p+1\right)B(N,N+p+1)\\[7pt]
&\quad-\frac{2^{2N}+N-1}{N-1}B\left(\frac{1}{2};N+p+1,N\right)B(N,p+1)\\[7pt]
&\quad+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{(2t-1)^p}{t^{N+p+1}}\left[\frac{1}{2^{N+p}}+\frac{2^{2N}}{N-1}(1-t)^{N-1}\right]B(t;N+p+1,N)\,\text{d}t.
\end{split}\end{equation}
with the final integral containing a single beta function, with a simple first argument.

**Edit2:** I found something that could be useful [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585208/evaluating-a-certain-integral-which-generalizes-the-3f-2-hypergeometric-fun?rq=1), and the formula cited there [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/280873612_On_some_formulas_for_the_Appell_function_F3_aa'_b_b'_c_w_z). By first using Eq. (\ref{eq1}) in $I^{(p)}(N)$ and then the relation
$$B(z;a,b)=\frac{z^a(1-z)^{b-1}}{a}{}_2F_1\left(1,1-b;a+1;\frac{z}{z-1}\right),$$
the starting integral can be rewritten with the hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1$ in the following form (here I neglect the terms that can be easily integrated)
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
I^{(p)}(N)&=\, ...\,-\frac{1}{N}\int_0^1\frac{t^{2N-1}(1-t)^p}{(1+t)^{2N+p}}\left\{\frac{1}{2^{N+p}}\left(\frac{1+t}{t}\right)^{N-1}\right.\\[7pt]
&\left.\quad+\frac{2^{2N-1}}{N-1}\left[(N+p+1)t-(N-2)\right]\right\}{}_2F_1(1,-N-p;N+1;-t)\,\text{d}t.
\end{split}\end{equation}
Now it is easy to see that the three terms are all of the form given in the link above. In particular, the first one can be expressed with the [Appell series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appell_series) $F_3$ according to the cited reference (I checked this result numerically with Mathematica)
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
&\int_0^1\frac{t^N(1-t)^p}{(1+t)^{N+p+1}}{}_2F_1(1,-N-p;N+1;-t)\,\text{d}t\\[7pt]
&\quad=\frac{B(N+1,p+1)}{2^{N+p+1}}F_3\left(N+p+1,1,p+1,-N-p,N+p+2;\frac{1}{2};-1\right).
\end{split}\end{equation}
The problem is that this result does not hold for the second and third terms, due to the fact that the third argument of ${}_2F_1$ (i.e. $N+1$) differs from the exponent of $t$ plus one ($2N+1$ and $2N$ respectively). Furthermore, I am not sure if further simplifications are possible.